# Delay in ViewPager touch event

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using ViewPager in Activity, whose adapter is a subclass of FragmentStatePagerAdapter. I have only three pages and each page show a view generated by Fragment(not complicated view).

My issue is: every time when I load the viewpager, I have to wait nearly 3 seconds before I can swipe left/right. The time interval between onCreate and onResume is less than 0.3 second

My question is: what's the potential root causes for this kind of delay?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you could post some code that would be great, but if i was going to take a stab...

I would say that you have many items in the adapter, and you have set the setOffscreenPageLimit(int) too high, and the viewpager is loading the fragments of too many pages.